How to optimize memory usage on a Scrapyd server?
When dealing with large-scale scraping (500,000 - 100,000,000 items), over time the Scrapyd server begins to consume all available memory (62 GB). Even when there are no items and the server is in "idle mode" (I use a Redis queue for start URLs), the memory isn't freed. Are there any effective ways to optimize memory usage or clear memory during idle time? (I've disabled logs and items.)
Stack: scrapy, scrapyd, scrapyd-client, scrapy-redis, mongodb.

Are you sure it's scrapyd itself?

@wRAR course, I can see the server processes (just using htop). Besides, only Scrapyd is running on the server (data is being sent to MongoDB (on a different machine).)...

or do you mean scrapy spider itself can take memory?

Of course spider processes can take a lot of memory, but you are sure it's scrapyd itself, so...
